# What type of wood is this scrap piece?

Tags: wood, hardwood

I picked up this slab of wood from my local Woodcraft in the scrap pile but have no idea what it is.

This particular piece is 8x12x2".

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Those pictures are all the same one piece of wood? 1st one *looks like* pine. 3rd one *is* oak, IMO. 2 and 4 are undiscernible to me w/o sanding.

Comment: @Mazura Same piece, yes. Though the color in that 2nd one seems...off (must have been something up w/ the white balance on the camera). The other 3 are what the true color is. The photos are just different sides of the same slab.

Comment: Looks like red wood to me because of the fuzzy grain and how gray it is. Redwood is a soft wood that is verry rot resistant.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Judging by the rays in the third picture (and the classic look of every floor I've ever worked on that wasn't maple), it's White Oak. And we can't see any knots, so it's specifically **Clear White Oak**.

[image]

([source](http://minuspink.com/maple-vs-oak-flooring/maple-vs-oak-flooring-on-floor-in-versus-meze-blog-1/))